# What is this green micro-organism found living in water?

Tags: species-identification, microbiology, chloroplasts, phycology

I study biology in France and experiment on water filtration with plants. I found that some chlorophyll-containing micro-organisms (about 10 micrometers in length) were raised in my basin.

[image]

[image]

I can't decide if this is a eukaryote (it looks like there are cellular compartments) or a prokaryote (it's very small!). I thought it could also be a cyanobacterium, that combines features of both prokaryotes and eukaryotes. Any ideas what this is?

Answer (score 16):

> I can't decide if it's a eukaryote or a prokaryote.

Well, that's certainly an eukaryote. We can clearly see the nuclei in the cells of your fist picture, as well as in the cells of your second one (not so clearly, though):

[image]

In the image above, the arrow starts right on one of the nucleus of that group of (apparently) three cells.

Besides that, despite some cyanobacteria being very long, 10µm is a lot for a prokaryote. The mean size of cyanobacteria is way less than that.

By the way, this:

> ... a prokaryote **or** a cyanobacteria (that can combine both characteristics)

Doesn't make much sense, because cyanobacteria **are** prokaryotes. More precisely, they are Eubacteria prokaryotes.

Finally, what eukaryoyte is this? I can't tell. It's most probably a kind of [Chlorophyta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorophyta), but I'm not able to go to the Class level. If you're interested in identifying it, you can try a taxonomic key. This one is for British freshwater algal flora, I don't know how different French algae are from the british ones: *[The Freshwater Algal Flora of the British Isles: An Identification Guide to Freshwater and Terrestrial Algae](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=Sc4897dfM_MC&pg=PA287&lpg=PA287&dq=unicellular%20chlorophyta%20identification&source=bl&ots=n4iErgFLKL&sig=WG07-hcoVmKr_CmvPiJy5X6zn9w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjU74uk693TAhWBV7wKHdwdDJAQ6AEIMDAC#v=onepage&q=unicellular%20chlorophyta%20identification&f=false)*.

If I'd guess (and this is a wild guess), I'd say that this is a Chlorellales, as the famous *Chlorella*:

[image]

Also, have in mind that saying *"that's an alga"* doesn't help as well: worse than paraphyletic, *algae*  is a polyphyletic group and, in biology, polyphyletic groups mean almost nothing.

Answer (score 5):

Have you considered that it might be algae? (I think it is.)

[image]

There are many kinds of algae. I couldn't tell you which one yours is.

[Algae Under Microscope](http://www.keywordsuggests.com/Y*niaRf8M|fCU3Wb*d6kwPAnJ9VUaxu4tE4jyyQudqM/)